# jquery bind form submission and anchor in single call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this code (which works just fine):

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <a id="btn">add</a>
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('form').submit(foo);
  $('#btn').click(foo);
});

function foo() {
  //do some stuff
}
```

I am currently binding the foo function to both the form submission, and the anchor click. But, I actually prefer not to have the form, although it seems to be the easiest way to bind the enter key on the textbox to the foo function.

What is the easiest way to achieve both bindings in one single statement, without the form, and without binding the textbox to a keypress and checking the keycode == 13? Is there a built in event I can bind to for the enter key on the textbox?

To explain with some pseudo code, this is roughly what I would like it to look like:

```
//get rid of the form
<input type="text" class="submit"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="submit" id="btn">add</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
  //and only have one binding statement
  $('.submit').bind('click enterPressed', foo);
});

function foo() {
  //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no ready-made event called `enterPressed` or any event for that matter that just responds to the enter key. **The short answer is, therefore, there's no way to achieve what you've asked**. **The long answer is below**, if you're open to creating a custom event, `enterPressed`.

You can define a custom event called `enterPressed` on the `input` element, and then you would have to prevent the `input` element from responding to any click events:

```
$(function() {
   $('input.submit').on('keypress', function(e) {
       e.which !== 13 || $(this).trigger( 'enterPressed' );
   })
   .on('click',function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });

    $('.submit').on('click enterPressed', foo);

    function foo() {
        console.log( 'foo called' );
    }
});
```

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/X3UhU/1/)

Comment: +1 very helpful answer. Help me understand this better ... why would we "have to prevent the click event on the input element from responding to any click handlers"? (And then we add `foo` as a click handler on both .submit elements)

Comment: @LarsH maybe my choice of words is not the best -- may be someone else might explain it better -- let me try though. You want to make sure that when the `input` element is clicked, the function `foo` does not fire -- my thinking is that the user is clicking so they can type some input, then when done they can press enter or click the link. That way when the `foo` is fired, the user's data has been entered. As you know, both the 'click` and the 'enterPressed` events are attached to both the `.submit` elements by: `$('.submit').on('click enterPressed', foo);`

Comment: this is the only correct answer so far, as the other solution will trigger when the mouse clicks on the textbox. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For your enterPressed event you can do this. Trigger your custom event:

```
$('#element').keyup(function(event) {
  if(event.which === 13) $('#element').trigger('enterPressed');
});
```

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events including the custom one:

```
$('#element').on('click enterPressed', function() {
  ...
});
```

Not sure about the code. But it should give you something to look up.

Comment: How would you apply this to the question? The OP wants to call `foo()` when Enter is pressed, "without binding the textbox to a keypress and checking the keycode == 13."

Comment: `What is the easiest way to achieve both bindings in one single statement`. This is the easiest way to bind multiple events and in the other case he'd have to create a custom event no going around it.

Comment: unfortunately this solution will trigger when the mouse clicks on the textbox

Comment: Well I wasnt going to write the entire answer for you. I was just trying to explain custom events.